# array part of API response showing as undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios

Im trying to make a simple weather-app using openweathermap but keep getting stuck on same problem. For some reason I can render most of the API response except the part with array in it, which gives the following error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')".

```
const WeatherDisplay = (props) => {
  if (props.showDisplay === false) {
    return null
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <div>
      Weather in {props.city.name}
      </div>
      <div>
        {props.city.main?.temp}
      </div>
      <div>
        {props.city.weather[0]?.main}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [city, setCity] = useState({})
  const [newSearch, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [showDisplay, setShowDisplay] = useState(false)


  const getWeather = () => {
    weatherService
    .getCity(newSearch)
    .then(response => {
      setCity(response.data)
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response.data)
    })
  }

  const handleShowWeather = () => {
    getWeather()
    setShowDisplay(true)
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        Weatherapp
      </header>
      <div>
        <FindCity newSearch={newSearch} handleSearchChange={handleSearchChange} handleShowWeather={handleShowWeather} />
        <WeatherDisplay showDisplay={showDisplay} city={city} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

API response:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -0.1257,
    "lat": 51.5085
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 804,
      "main": "Clouds",
      "description": "overcast clouds",
      "icon": "04d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 293.06,
    "feels_like": 293.04,
    "temp_min": 290.95,
    "temp_max": 294.82,
    "pressure": 1015,
    "humidity": 74
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 5.66,
    "deg": 240
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 99
  },
  "dt": 1696955247,
  "sys": {
    "type": 2,
    "id": 2006068,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1696918507,
    "sunset": 1696958389
  },
  "timezone": 3600,
  "id": 2643743,
  "name": "London",
  "cod": 200
}
```

At first I ran into same problem with {props.city.main.temp}, but fixed it by changing it into {props.city.main?.temp}. I also don't understand why {props.city.name} doesn't require it as well.  It's almost as the render is too fast for the API call to keep up. What would be the right way to go about this?

Comment: You are initializing `city` with an empty object. Thus on the initial render, it tries to access `{}.weather[0]` but as the empty object does not have a weather property you are trying to access the first element of an undefined array. The others work because you access them conditionally like `city.main?.temp` which is ok even if the `main` property doesn't exist which is the case on the initial render. Use `city.weather?.[0]?.main` instead.

Comment: Hey thanks, that seems to be working!